# Unable to ssh into a system

Tags: server, ssh

We have more than 500 systems running ubuntu. When i access a machine through ssh few machines are not getting logged in, rest of the machines are logging in successfully. I am entering the correct username and password. Eventhough it is not getting connected. Pls look at the below snapshot.

[image: ssh error]

Pls see the output in the following link.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/611748/

Comment: try using "ssh -v" so that you can see and paste more debug information

Comment: If you have access to the remote machine, `/var/log/auth.log` would be interesting too.

Comment: @karthick87  and you might want to remove the IP adres in the top bar too ;)

Comment: You'd better switch from password to keybased authentication, it makes administration much safer and easier. Easier because you can use `ssh-keyadd` to store password-protected keyfiles. Safer because brute-forcing is less feasible.

Comment: Also check if the permissions are set right on the remote system. File permissions that is.

Comment: From the legal SSH banner I assume that those servers have a formal security policy. Such policies usually have strict requirements in what respects to failed login attempts, password age, etc. It is likely that your account is locked out. Please contact the system administrator to check it.

Comment: There is no such person here. I am maintaining all these right now. However from only one system i am able to ssh into that machine. How come possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the contents of /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the target machine - it is possible that your specific user is not permitted to log in remotely.  Specific lines to check for:

`PermitRootLogin no`   # should never allow remote root login

`AllowUsers someusername`  # whitelist of users who are allowed to ssh to the machine

You can probably do a comparison of that file from one of the working machines to see if any lines are different.

Comment: I just want to give ssh rights to only one IP address say '172.29.32.9' so how can i do this? Also i would like to display some warning messages if some one ssh into the sytem.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from ssh -v, Try  `ssh -vv`, `ssh -vvv` to increase verbosity of error messages to figure out what is happening.

If all cases fails,

Try from other servers to login as '`ssh username@host`' and try other usernames as '`ssh username1@host`'

if you can login  to console, try 'ssh 0' from same system so that you can check if ssh subsystem works fine.

If ssh 0 works, ssh subsystem is fine. If not, Try  to restart ssh subsystem

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```